# Run a terminal command when device connects to a WiFi network

Tags: bash, shell, wifi, mac-address, spoofing

I spoof my MAC address on a public WiFi network that I use often, but I do not want to have my MAC spoofed on my home network. I was thinking that a way to automate this is to have the computer automatically reset its MAC address with

`sudo spoof-mac reset wi-fi`

using [SpoofMAC](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC). How could I automate this, so that every time my computer connects to *x* network, that command gets run, and my MAC address gets set back to normal?

I am on MacOS Monterey.

Comment: It would depend on what distribution you are running and what you are using to manage your various network connections.

Comment: @ivanivan i am on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Add a [cron](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) job to run this bash script every 1 min:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(iwgetid -r) = "Home WI-FI" ]; then
    sudo spoof-mac reset wi-fi
else
    command to be executed here
fi
```